# Windows 7 64-bit Pro not connecting to SQL Server on domain Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, windows-xp

I am upgrading computers from Windows XP Professional to Windows 7 Professional but I have a problem getting one of the stock control software programs we use to connect to our SQL Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard from the new Windows 7 computers.

Our computers are connected to a domain and so is the SQL Server. The Windows XP computers allows each standard domain user to log on and connect to the SQL Server via the stock control software program.

But on the Windows 7 Pro computers standard domain users can't connect to the SQL Server but the domain administrator accounts on the same Windows 7 Pro computers can connect to the SQL Server via the stock control program.

I have setup the server alias, server name and port number via the SQL Server Client Network Utility (`cliconfg.exe`) so I know this isn't the problem as it works when I am logged on as domain administrator.

It seems to be something to do with domain user permissions and Windows 7 Pro. There seems to be a change from Windows XP Pro to Windows 7 Pro that doesn't allow standard domain users to connect to an SQL Server. But I can't find anything about this and can't workout how to fix it except to make all the users domain administrators which is obviously not a good thing to do. So basically I I think I need to create a group policy that allows the users to connect to the SQL Server but I have no experience doing this and don't know where to begin.

Thanks for all you guys help and I hope someone can provide me with the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out that the UAC (User Access Control) is what was blocking the stock control program from connecting to the SQL Server.